# On a two monitor setup how can I keep the game (TF2) open when I click on a tab in the other monitor?

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2

If I have TF2 open on one monitor if I click on any other tab in the second monitor it minimizes the game.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 25):

**You can switch windows without minimizing by using Borderless windowed mode.**

This can be done in a couple ways, the easiest is by going into your "Options> Video" settings in game and setting the game to "Run in a Window".

[image: Options]

Alternatively you can modify your launch settings by adding the launch options `-windowed -noborder` in the TF2s "Properties > General" settings directly in Steam.

[Source - an in-depth tutorial on Bordeless Windowed mode for TF2](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=181352997)

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there be a reason why someone would not want to keep this setting on all the time?

Comment: @KodosJohnson - Performance. Real full screen is easier on the computer than borderless windows.

Comment: This may also effect the catching of the mouse cursor when it hits the border between the two screens. Not familiar with TF2 but different games handle this differently.

Comment: Worth noting the command line works only in all Source engine games

Comment: The border catching is a common issue in RTS games opened in window mode, where you want to do border scrolling.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the setting you're looking for is borderless windowed mode in team fortress 2. As the name suggests, it puts the game in windowed mode but removes the border, so it should still appear as full screen. That should fix your issue and allow you to click without minimizing!

Answer (score 4):

I addition to the in-game option mentioned in the main answer, you can use Steam Launch options - I use these for Counter Strike and they work for TF2 as well.

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1040-JWMT-2947

> -window -noborder -novid -nojoy -w 2560 -h 1080

[image]

Comment: One thing to note is that your launch properties are doing more than just setting the game to borderless windowed. It is also setting the height and width of the window to that of 21:9 ultrawide monitor, turning off joystick support, and turning off the intro video. How to set the properties for borderless window is described in the answer above

Comment: @Malco I could clarify that my setup does more than simply "borderless windowed". I assumed that anyone smart enough to ask these questions could read the link from Steam and see the options do more than 2 things.

Comment: @ WernerCD That would probably be a good idea, you never know with people on the internet. you would be surprised by the number of "why dis no work?????" questions that show up in the queue some days. Plus clearer is always better.

Answer (score 0):

Sup.
One thing you can do is on your keyboard press **WIN+MAJ+*left arrow key*** and boom, there you go.

im not sure this work but i researched tf2 *fullscreen 2nd screen* and this is the answer. [image: Google,TF2,TF,TeamF,Teamfortress,Team Fortress, Team fortress 2, TF2 fullscreen, monitor, 2nd monitor, answer]

Comment: MAJ? Are you french? Even your image says "Shift", why did you decided to confuse someone?

Comment: Your bar for what constitutes research is very low..

Comment: Yo shit im not undercover anymore

Comment: @MADPYRO French... TF2... put it all together and we get... *gasp* YOU'RE THE SPY!